# How to use lists of strings in a column of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which includes a feature, named B here, that has list of values:

df

```
A         B
t8    ab1r,tvc3b,cdv5s,tad7  
t9    trg1br    
t2    trg6b,t9try,ab1r,t8sf,t10hg   
t2    t20hj,tad7'
...     ...
```

What is a good way to normalize feature B in this dataframe to build a model?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Repeating each row of the feature A for all the strings in the corresponding row  of B seems a good output. For example, the first row will change to four rows, i.e., (t8 ab1r) (t8 tvc3b) (t8 cdv5s) (t8 tad7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode())
print(df)

    A       B
0  t8    ab1r
0  t8   tvc3b
0  t8   cdv5s
0  t8    tad7
1  t9  trg1br
2  t2   trg6b
2  t2   t9try
2  t2    ab1r
2  t2    t8sf
2  t2   t10hg
3  t2   t20hj
3  t2   tad7'
```

Comment: That's what I needed! I am a beginner in pandas!

Comment: Glad that worked. You can also use `.reset_index()` at the end to reset the index values